# Tagdiv Composer loads to infinity: Wordpress Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress.
I am working on a news website with the **Newspaper theme** and **Tagdiv composer plugin**

After working for a week I have developed a problem which I explain below.

Whenever I want to edit pages with TagDiv Composer, the large spinner icon shows and starts loading. It stays there like forever until I close the page.
In the console (from Developer Tools), I found 2 errors which are shown in the pictures below. The error are actually from in `js_files_for_wrapper.min.js`

[image: Error One] 
[image: Error Two]

I identified the actual error for Error 1 one this line of code `JSON.stringify([d[0].shortcode.attrs.named])` so I made the following deductions:

The problem started after I saved a custom shortcode named ***“shortcode“*** which I think is an object in the **`js_files_for_wrapper.min.js`** as per the error line above.

If what I think about the cause is true, could anyone help me with identifying where the custom shortcode I created was saved, and how to delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to contact the theme support because my account was compromised.
However, after long testing and failing, I finally resolved to **resetting the theme options** from the theme panel.
That solved it, although I had to set my custom colours and fonts, as well as custom CSS all over again.

Answer (score 0):

Was having a similar issue on a brand new theme setup. tagdiv Composer was loading to infinity. Further, my Header and Footer menus were not showing. Had to click to activate the Header and Footer check boxes on this URL, which fixe things: https://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=tdb_cloud_templates

Comment: Please post detailed answer and then references.